# Does Google Firebase's arrayUnion() reliably append data to the end of an array?

Tags: arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't find confirmation on StackOverflow or Google's docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

If I use `arrayUnion()` to add to a Firebase array, what does Firebase do about ordering?  Does it append to the end?  If the element already exists say midway through an array [a, b, EXISTS, c], then `arrayUnion()` will just leave it in place?

I need to maintain a list of contacts ordered by the `Person` last chatted with, essentially an implicit chronology. Potentially the list needs to be reordered each time a new message is received.  I'm wondering if the best way to do this is `arrayRemove()` then `arrayUnion()` to shuffle the most recently chatting `Person`, or whether to check if the array needs changing and just rebuild the whole array and use a transaction.

There could be simultaneous mutations of my contacts array, so the method Firebase can process quickest is of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-arrayunion) the elements that are already in the array are not added, and only the new elements are appended at the end of the array.

Lets say you have array `[A,B,C]` and use `arrayUnion` with `[A.D,Z]`
The resulting array will be: `[A,B,C,D,Z]`

To keep the mentioned order the `arrayRemove()` and `arrayUnion()` work, however for performance keep in mind that this is efficient only if adding and removing a few elements at a time.

Comment: Hey @jose that's a great answer, I'll tick it directly, thankyou.  I'll be adding or reordering 1 item at a time, each time a new Chat msg is sent, so to confirm for a single addition I should upload a fresh version of the array to my Firebase record?  And avoid 2 direct array operations?  Thanks for all your attentions.

Comment: For one item at a time `arrayRemove` and `arrayUnion` this will be two actions on Firesstore, however adding the full array each time deoending on your data structure will be one operation per document affected.